# css not repositioning text

Tags: html, css

Im trying to reposition text on my page with css but im changing the values and nothing is changing, correct me if im wrong but im pretty sure im ddoing everything right.

HTML

```
<div id="leftblock">
    <a href="shop" style=" text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Helvetica ;font-size: 30px ;">SHOP</a>
</div>



<div id="rightBlock">
    <a href="http://instagram.com/" style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: Helvetica ;font-size: 30px ;">INSTAGRAM</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#leftblock {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 12%;
}

#rightBlock {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90%;
    left: 80%;
}
```

The elements would be in my desired location with this css when i had it all on the same file, but now since i added the external stylesheet and placed the positioning on there the elements stay in the top left and don't move.

(Yes i linked the stylesheet properly `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`)

Comment: Check once if the styles are applying or not by inspecting in the browser.

Comment: It works fine for me, where did you put the <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> part in the html file

Comment: Try to delete cashe from browser ?

Comment: @Sachi.Dila i placed it in the <head></head>

Comment: @Anji so i do see the elements in their proper spot now, but I cannot see the text because it is behind the video. I changed z-index to 1 but i still cannot see the text

Comment: Did you remove the <style> tag from the head? I might override the external styles

Comment: @james you have the style.css and html file in same place right?, not in separate locations

Comment: @Sachi.Dila yes same project

Comment: hard reload/refresh your browser for chrome i think shift+F5? use F12 to inspect element

Comment: @james can you show the <head> tag part

Comment: @BobbyAxe ya when i refresh i can see the elements i have in the right locations, but its behind the background which is a video, do you know how i would go about bringing it to the front?

Comment: use/add `z-index: 10;` to the css property

Comment: `z-index: 2` simply means how close to you an element is the higher the value the closer the element is to you but be careful for the element may over shadow other elements making it difficult for you to click them

Comment: Are you saying the original problem is solved now? Then you should edit the question to reflect the new situation. Does the video have a `z-index`?

Comment: Where in relation to the HTML file did you put the CSS? Do they both reside in the same directory, or do their paths differ? I recommend you check the browser's console for any 403s or 404s which would indicate that resources aren't loaded.